# How to redirect user on another page depending on location using JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a simple script to redirect users on different pages depending on their location.

Basically, the https://ipapi.co/country/ page is returning a value based on locations, such as "GB" - for the UK. So when the script returns "GB", the user should be redirected to UK.html.

You can notice that in the second condition, I am trying to use an array of countries. If the user is from IT or FR or DE, then I want him redirected to EU.html.

Because I'm a complete beginner, I think something is missing in the following code and I hope you can help me understand what is missing and what would be the correct code to write.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.get('https://ipapi.co/country/', function(country){
console.log(country)
})

if (country = "GB") {
  window.location.replace("UK.html");
}
else if (country = ["FR","IT","DE","CH"]) {
  window.location.replace("EU.html");
}
else {
  window.location.replace("US.html");
}

</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change window.location.replace("US.html") to window.location="US.html"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('https://ipapi.co/country/', function(country){
console.log(country)
})
if (country === "GB") {
 window.location="UK.html";
}
else if (["FR","IT","DE","CH"].indexOf(country )!==-1) {
  window.location="EU.html";
}
else {
  window.location="US.html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked with a slight modification. Just had to move the "})" from just after console.log(country) to the end of the script. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a simple solution which does not require jQuery.

One function will make a request to `https://ipapi.co/country/`.

A second function will perform the redirect depending on the response of the first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const whatCountry = function(){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("GET", "https://ipapi.co/country/")
    xhr.onload = function(){
        checkCountryAndRedirect(xhr.response)
    }
    xhr.send()
}

const checkCountryAndRedirect = function(country){
    if(country === "GB"){
        window.location.replace("UK.html");
    } else if(country === "FR" || country === "IT" || country === "DE" || country === "CH"){
        window.location.replace("EU.html")
    } else {
        window.location.replace("US.html")
    }
}
</script>
```

Once these two functions are defined, you can call the request with `whatCountry()`

To clarify, the part of your code that checks for `country` must be part of the callback, as AJAX requests are asynchronous.

The `if` checks you are doing will always evaluate to true, because a single `=` indicates that you are assigning the value on the right to `country`.

The second `if` statement would be checking whether `country` was the array `["FR","IT","DE","CH"]`. To check whether `country` was one of those four countries, you can test whether `country` is equal to each of those countries (not a very clean solution). You can also use `switch` statements, but I like the `indexOf` solution suggested above.

EDIT: I have used `window.location.replace` but `window.location = ...` would be more suited to your case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it!

Comment: @quasarnibiru Happy to help :)